# Topological Sort Algorithm Comparison for DAG: BFS vs DFS

Tags: time-complexity, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, topological-sort

I was comparing two topological sort algorithm based on DFS and BFS respectively. I have found out that for higher number of edges (around 50000 or more) BFS is faster than DFS. But I have read somewhere that DFS is supposed to be slower than BFS. But their time complexity is both O(V + E). So which is true? They should take same amount of time or one of them must be faster?

Hi. I was comparing two topological sort algorithm based on DFS and BFS respectively. On the DFS based approach after finishing each vertex, it was inserted onto the front of a linked list. And at the end, the whole list was reversed to get the final result. For the case of BFS, I used Kahn's algorithm to get a topological sort.
To compare the execution time for topological sort (Time complexity) I used Random Graph generator to generate directed acyclic graphs of different number of vertices and edges. I have found out that for higher number of edges (around 500 or more) BFS is faster than DFS. But I have read somewhere that DFS is supposed to be slower than BFS. But their time complexity is both O(V + E). Although as in my code I have added a reverse command for the list, the complexity for DFS based approach should be O(V + E + V) = O(2V + E).
Am I doing something wrong? Or is BFS actually faster than DFS for higher number of edges for topological sort?

Comment: Having the same time complexity does not mean they should be equally efficient. Other than that, there is no way for us to know if you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: Can DFS be faster than BFS for a high number of edges?

Comment: That probably depends on a lot of things.

Comment: @T.I.Mahmud The point is that algorithms A and B can have the same time complexity, even if A is 1000 times slower than B.